Mark email's follow up status as Complete in Outlook 365 via code
I have a VBA code in Outlook 365 that reads emails in a secondary mailbox[Common mailbox for email triggers from ERP] I'm reading emails that have a specific Subject line and collate the email body data[this is in XML] in an excel file.
Once the email is read, mark the email as "read" & mark email's follow-up status as Complete[The tick mark].
I've been looking it on Google but unable to find any solution that works. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Below are the various options that I've tried. Only able to mark the email as Read is working.
`For Each olItem In olFilteredItems
    If TypeOf olItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set olMail = olItem
        If olMail.UnRead Then
            totalEmails = totalEmails + 1

            ' Mark email as read
            olMail.UnRead = False
            olMail.Categories = "Completed" ' Assign the category

            olMail.Save ' This fails explixitly


            olMail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
            olMail.IsMarkedAsTask
            olMail.MarkAsTaskComplete
            olMail.MarkAsTask

        End If
    End If
Next olItem`

EDIT: All of the above were individual tries, mark email's follow up flag as Complete, Mark email as task and then mark it as complete, Assign a custom or pre-built category to the email, none of it works and no error too.
but I get error when I try to save the email Obj, everytime.
Run time error 2147221223 (80040119)
objMail.Save

.Save is too early, it should follow the attempted update.

What is the actual error? You might want to move setting the Unread property to the very end after you set all the other properties and call Save - read/unread state is not an intrinsic message property, and Save is not required for it, even though it can cause a conflict error.

I Apologize if I wasn't too clear in my initial message[First time poster]. All the options that are listed above, I've tried them separately. Mark Followup flag as complete, Mark email as task and then mark it as Complete, Mark email as a custom or pre-defined category - Nothing works, no error. And when I try mailItem.save after any of the aforementioned activity, it always throws error
Run time error 2147221223 (80040119)
objMail.Save

Re: Run time error 2147221223 (80040119) - Since you have Outlook.MailItem rather than MailItem, is the code in an application other than Outlook?

@niton The code is within Outlook VBA. I'm not that VBA code savvy, but if I do not use Outlook.MailItem will the Standalone MailItem just work?

Outlook.MailItem is the same as MailItem if the code is in Outlook.

The save error is not relevant if you cannot update FlagStatus.

In my experience, FlagStatus code is ineffective for IMAP. Follow Up Flags and Reminders for IMAP accounts and Outlook Categories, Flags, and IMAP Accounts. Remove the flag in Flag email messages for follow up shows the flags available where FlagStatus code has an impact.

@niton I don't think it's IMP. It's a corporate mailbox that is MS Exchange i believe. and I can see the options of setting flags, followup, followup date & time etc on the application. it's just that the VBA code is not making any changes, neither is there any error on these commands except for mailItem.Save.

Assuming you are on not on IMAP How do I tell if I have an Exchange account in Outlook since the follow up flags are available appears there is an issue outside my experience.
